# Using DataGridView to Update Multiple Tables

Tags: database, vb.net, dataset, tableadapter

On a VB.NET 2008 form I have a DataGridView, BindingSource and TableAdapter.

The BindingSource DataSource is a dataset.

In the dataset I have a Fill command that joins three tables and this is displayed without a problem in the DataGridView.

However, I am unable to Update the dataGridView because it has multiple tables from a single TableAdapter?

Does anyone know a simple way I can update.  The tables has over 200 columns and I only want to update the columns that are changed.  If I use a single table I can edit data in the DataGridView and the database is updated ok.

Any help would be appreciated?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `Windows.Forms BindingSource`, does not support complex properties (which I assume you are after).

You would have to craft your own custom `BindingSource` (and it will likely be bespoke to you) to handle complex property values and assignments.