# Datagridview - Oracle Update error "Dynamic SQL generation failed."

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, datagridview

I'm using Datagridview to show me joined records from 2 tables. Data that is showing is from one of the tables + data that are in joined table (Table3). SQL query returns results in Datagridview (works fine in Oracle too), but update fails with "**Dynamic SQL generation failed. Either no base tables were found or more than one base table was found**". Here is my table design:

```
Table1:

ID_TABLE1
ITEM_NAME
ITEM_DESCRIPTION

Table3: (this is a joined view for Table1 and Table2)
ID_TABLE3
ID_TABLE1_FK
ID_TABLE3_FK
VALIDITY
DATE_CONNECTION
```

My code (exactly as Oracle recommends):

```
       Public Class Form2

            Private da As OracleDataAdapter
            Private cb As OracleCommandBuilder
            Private ds As DataSet

            Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                    Saving.Enabled = False 'this deals with error with updating (from Oracle site)
             Dim SQL As String = "SELECT ID_TABLE1, ID_TABLE3, SERIAL_NO, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_DESCRIPTION, VALIDITY, DATE_CONNECTION from TABLE1, TABLE2 WHERE TABLE3.ID_TABLE1_FK=" & Form1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString

                Try

                    Oracleconn() 'connection to my DB
                    Dim cmd = New OracleCommand(SQL, Oracleconn)
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    da = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
                    cb = New OracleCommandBuilder(da)
                    ds = New DataSet()
                    da.Fill(ds)

                    My_DGV.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                    Saving.Enabled = True

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

                Finally
                'No closing of connection here because of working with Dataset (Oracle suggestion)
                End Try
            End Sub

           Private Sub Saving
              da.Update(ds.Tables(0))
              Saving.Enabled = True
            End Sub

       End Class
```

So, Is my SQL query wrong or what ? Any help would be much appreciated !

P.S.: In actual case only column "VALIDITY" from Table3 will be allowed to change for users, so I need to update only that field.

Comment: Check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666425/using-datagridview-to-update-multiple-tables

Comment: @phonetic_man, thanks for link. My assumption is probably right, SQL should be constructed with JOIN. Though I can't figure out correct synthax for It :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too complicated for me, looks like Oracle-provided suggestion for working with Datasets just isn't easy when you want to perform Update on join table records. So I tried a different approach and It worked for me. Since what I need is to update only 1 column from SQL query which returns to Datagridview I did this :

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In My_.Rows

       cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("validity", row.Cells(6).Value))
       cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE TABLE3 SET VALIDITY= : validity WHERE ID_TABLE1_FK='" & row.Cells(1).Value & "'"

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
       cmd.Parameters.Clear()

Next
```

If anyone knows the answer to my original question - so how to do same with just  da.Update(ds.Tables(0)), then please let me know. I reckon that SQL query needs to be properly changed, using JOIN method.